# Python file write() stuck in append mode when read() has byte count as parameter

Tags: python, file

Why do these two very similar codes behave so differently?

Code 1:

```
with open("new.txt", 'w+') as f:
    f.write("this is a line")

with open("new.txt", 'r+') as f:
    f.write("***")
    f.read()  # << note here
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Output: `***s is a line`

Code 2:

```
with open("new.txt", 'w+') as f:
    f.write("this is a line")

with open("new.txt", 'r+') as f:
    f.write("***")
    f.read(1)  # << note here
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Output: `this is a line***`

Python version: `Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: Looks like not specifying a count argument causes the writes to be flushed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate any solution? I am still learning Python.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Python

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo someone told me that this behaviour is related to Windows file I/O. But I am new to file programming in general, so I have no idea of any of this.

Comment: I can repro this on MacOS. (`Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 15 2022, 05:43:36) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin`)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks. I tried on Cygwin and WSL2. Same bug.

Comment: Same on `Python 3.9.6 (default, Sep 24 2021, 19:09:16) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux`. It seems to be platform independent.

Comment: tried the old Python versions. It seems Issue started with Python 3.3.

Comment: Good find. I've submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/115059) for this issue.

Comment: Note that this bug is specific to the C implementation of the `io` module, so until the bug is fixed you can work around it by using the Python implementation of the `io` module instead by adding `from _pyio import open`.